# Finite dimensional algebraic representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I heard that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is the unique algebraic irreducible representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ with dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Would you let me know what is such representation?

I will appreciate you if you describe such representation.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is just the $(n - 1)$st symmetric power $S^{n - 1} \Bbb V$ of the standard (or defining) representation $\Bbb V$, which we can identify with the space of homogenous polynomials $p \in \Bbb C[x, y]$ of degree $n - 1$.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your kind reply. Then if $n=1$, then is it the trivial representation?

Comment: Yes, by definition any $1$-dimensional representation is trivial. The adjoint representation is $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C) \cong S^2 \Bbb V$.

Comment: @Travis not by definition, but because of various properties of the group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, forgive the garbling, which isn't even quite correct as stated. (Of course, I had in mind the unique trivial representation associated to any group.)

Comment: More generally, irreducible algebraic representations of $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ can naturally be parametrized by $(n-1)$-tuples of non-negative integers, with a "nice" formula for the dimension of the modules based on this tuple. For $n=2$ the formula says that the representation corresponding to the integer $k$ has dimension $k+1$ (and indeed in this case the representation corresponding to $k$ is $S^kV$ as mentioned above).

Comment: @Travis: a trivial representation can be in any dimension: pick any vector space and take the trivial action. But the only (up to isomorphism) trivial *irreducible* representation is in dimension 1.

Comment: @YCor Ugh, yes, of course, I somehow managed not to type "irreducible"...